# ImportError: No module named sip

Tags: python-3.x, centos-6.9

I have installed electrum alongwith python 3.4, But when i run electrum it gives me below error. And I installed pyqt5 without --no-deps.

`pip3.4 install pyqt5 --no-deps`

`pip3.4 install https://download.electrum.org/3.1.3/Electrum-3.1.3.tar.gz`

```
#electrum 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/electrum", line 418, in <module>
d.init_gui(config, plugins)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/electrum/daemon.py", line 308, in init_gui
gui = __import__('electrum_gui.' + gui_name, fromlist=['electrum_gui'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/electrum_gui/qt/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named 'sip'
```

I also upgraded pip. Getting error with deps:
`pip3.4 install pyqt5`

```
# pip3.4 install pyqt5
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Collecting sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: _And I installed pyqt5 without --no-deps._ What do you mean? The command you shared clearly includes the no-deps option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you are using Python 3.4.

According to the [documentation of PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html), if you install from wheel, Python 3.5 is the minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a Problem just try it**

First, activate your virtual env in your cmd using this,

```
./utfod/Scripts/activate
```

If error come like: `cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system`, Then for Solution execute this,

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

command first in powershell then

```
./utfod/Scripts/activate
```